# layout buttons within frame nested in tkk.Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't properly layout buttons within frame nested in tkk.Notebook

In Main.py I create ttk.Notebook and attach mainTab instance

```
root = tk.Tk()
rootFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=600, height=300)
rootFrame.grid(columnspan=1, rowspan=2)
rootFrame.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

tabs = ttk.Notebook(rootFrame)
tabs.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=1, rowspan=1)
mainTab     = ttk.Frame(tabs)
mainTab.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=6)

tabs.add(mainTab, text="Main")
rootFrame.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
mainPane = MainTab(root,mainTab)
root.mainloop()
```

- in mainTab.py I'm trying to insert buttonFrame and layout two buttons within it

```
class MainTab:
    ...
    def __init__(self, root, mainTab) -> None:
        self.root = root
        buttonFrame = tk.Frame(mainTab, bg="white")
        buttonFrame.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=3, rowspan=1)
        self.start_btn = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Start", command=lambda:self.start_timer(), font=BUTTON_FONT, bg="green", fg="white") # , height=1, width=14
        self.start_btn.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)
        self.reset_btn = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="X", command=lambda:self.reset_timer(), font=BUTTON_FONT, bg="green", fg="white") # , height=1, width=1
        self.reset_btn.grid(column=2, row=0)
        ...
```

As a result start button is not properly placed in the grid

[image]

It looks like buttonFrame takes full parent frame width and buttons placed in the middle regardless of their grid settings.
How I can properly layout buttons within buttonFrame?

Here is the requested "minimal reproducible example" which also look not good

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Time Tracker")
root.iconbitmap('./assets/logoTransp4icon24.ico')
rootFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=600, height=300)
rootFrame.grid(columnspan=1, rowspan=2)
rootFrame.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

tabs = ttk.Notebook(rootFrame)
tabs.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=1, rowspan=1)

mainTab     = ttk.Frame(tabs)
mainTab.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=6)

buttonFrame = tk.Frame(mainTab, bg="white")
buttonFrame.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=3, rowspan=1)
start_btn = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Start", command=lambda:self.start_timer(), font="Arial", bg="green", fg="white") # , height=1, width=14
start_btn.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)
reset_btn = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="X", command=lambda:self.reset_timer(), font="Arial", bg="green", fg="white") # , height=1, width=1
reset_btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

timerDisplay = tk.Label(mainTab, text="00:00:00", font="Arial")
timerDisplay.grid(columnspan=2, column=1, row=4)
tabs.add(mainTab, text="Main")
rootFrame.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Better post a [mre] to reproduce the output of the image.

Comment: @acw1668 sorry to remove not related code. My  learn project here https://github.com/JavaPantry/pomodoro-timer

Comment: `buttonFrame` is not used in your project code, so [mre] is required.

Comment: I thought that I attached it to mainTab with line `buttonFrame = tk.Frame(mainTab, bg="white")`

Comment: I mean the code in your project link, not your posted code.  Your posted code cannot reproduce the result of the image.

Comment: Try removing `columnspan=3` in `buttonFrame.grid(...)`.

Comment: I update post with minimal example.  Thanks for suggestion to do so. It's really clear picture. Sorry if I will not reply promptly. Here is almost midnight.

Comment: Wow "removing columnspan=3 in buttonFrame.grid(...)" Works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buttonFrame` occupies column 0 to 2 and `timerDisplay` occupies column 1 to 2.  So `timerDisplay` overlaps `buttonFrame`.  Removing `columnspan=3` in `buttonFrame.grid(...)` can fix the overlapping issue:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Time Tracker")
root.iconbitmap('./assets/logoTransp4icon24.ico')
rootFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=600, height=300)
#rootFrame.grid(columnspan=1, rowspan=2) # override by below line
rootFrame.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

tabs = ttk.Notebook(rootFrame)
tabs.grid(column=0, row=1, rowspan=1)

mainTab     = ttk.Frame(tabs)
#mainTab.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=6) # not necessary

buttonFrame = tk.Frame(mainTab, bg="white")
buttonFrame.grid(column=0, row=4, rowspan=1)  # removed columnspan=3
start_btn = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Start", command=lambda:self.start_timer(), font="Arial", bg="green", fg="white") # , height=1, width=14
start_btn.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)
reset_btn = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="X", command=lambda:self.reset_timer(), font="Arial", bg="green", fg="white") # , height=1, width=1
reset_btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

timerDisplay = tk.Label(mainTab, text="00:00:00", font="Arial")
timerDisplay.grid(columnspan=2, column=1, row=4)
tabs.add(mainTab, text="Main")
#rootFrame.pack(expand=1, fill="both") # already called above
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  These columnspan were the reason for this mess.